# Stochastic input to LTI systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

Papoulis stochastics processes book question 9-6 says:

Show that if $R_\nu(t_1,t_2)=q(t_1)\delta(t1-t2)$
and $\mathbf{w''}=\mathbf{v}(t)U(t)$ and $\mathbf{w}(0)=\mathbf{w'}(0)=0$ then

$E\{\mathbf{w}^2(t)\}=\int_{0}^{t}(t-\tau)^2q(\tau)d\tau$

There is a hint for this question in the book's supplimentory material that says you need to show that $\mathbf{w}(t)=\int_{0}^{t}(t-s)\nu(s)ds$. But I don't know how to show this. In fact when I differentiate it for t I don't get $\mathbf{w''}=\mathbf{v}(t)U(t)$.

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: I am back to university after quite some time, so please excuse me if you found some trivial mistakes. I am preparing for an exam, any help would be appriciated.